# Leetcode Contains Duplicate: Hash table confusion

Tags: python, hashtable

I'm trying to teach myself DS+A but struggling with some questions.

https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/

For this question, the first approach that came in my head was hash tables. I know you can do a one liner with sets, but I want to try using hash tables.

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        duplicates={}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if i in duplicates:
                return False
            return True
```

It passes 11/18 cases, but for the test case of [0], it returns True when the expected output is False. I can't seem to understand why it returns False.

I got it. Return statement was in too deep and I had to update it for every loop.

````
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        duplicates={}
        for i in nums:
            if i in duplicates:
                return True
            else:
                duplicates[i] = 0
        return False ```
````

Comment: do you want to check if `i` is in `duplicates` or if `nums[i]` is in `duplicates`? Where do you add elements to the hash table?

Comment: I want to check if any of the numbers in `nums` are in `duplicates`. If they are, it returns `True`, else `False`. The problem is that the testcase of [0] expects False, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Because 0 is not in duplicates. duplicates is always empty.